# Setting up RSpec and Devise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am setting up Rspec on my project and it also uses Devise. I follow the following steps found [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)). And when I run:

```
rspec spec
```

I got the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Devise::Test (NameError)
```

What I am doing wrong? I am using rails 3.2

Comment: seems like you need to `include DeviseHelpers` on your spec_helper.rb

Comment: As you can see on the link that I have included on my post, I have been included the DeviseHelper. Is there any difference if you include it on rails_helper?

Comment: that's fine.. then you need to `require "rails_helper"` on the spec files

Comment: What is the matter when I include it on `rails_helper.rb` and not doing it on `spec_helper.rb`. It is the same. It will still not work.

Comment: it doesn't .. you can include it on any file you want.. it's just that you need to require the file(whatever the name of the file is) on your spec files where you use devise methods for testing your specs.

Comment: of course not.. i don't have your specs.. i'm just trying to help based on what you've given on your question. `uninitialized constant Devise::Test` means that you're using this module.. on your specs.. and that module is not present there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the link that you followed above, it has this line:

```
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
```

Change that line to:

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

Refered here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4133